# HTML5 - multiple animations, different fps

Tags: html, requestanimationframe

I want to create an html5 game which contains multiple sprites.

For different elements I want to create an fixed fps.

For example:

Walk - 10 fps, so 10 sprites will be shown within 1 second

Run - 15 fps

Attack - 3 fps

How can I create this with requestAnimationFrame and not using set timeout or setinterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the timestamp feature of requestAnimationFrame to trigger animations at different desired frames-per-second

```
function animate(timestamp){
    // timestamp is a representation of the current elapsed time
}
```

The method is to set individual times when you want each action to be executed:

```
WalkTriggerTime = timest + 1000/desiredFPS;
```

Then do the action when the requestAnimationFrame timestamp exceeds this trigger time

```
if( timestamp > WalkTriggerTime ){ 

    // execute a walk 

    // and reset the trigger timer

    WalkTriggerTime = timest + 1000/desiredFPS;
}
```

Example Code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/D6SU8/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var animations=[]
    var fps03={x:20,y:20,fps:03,frameCount:0,triggerTime:null,}
    var fps10={x:20,y:40,fps:10,frameCount:0,triggerTime:null,}
    var fps15={x:20,y:60,fps:15,frameCount:0,triggerTime:null,}
    var stopAnimation=false;
    animations.push(fps03,fps10,fps15);

    for(var i=0;i<animations.length;i++){
        var a=animations[i];
        ctx.fillText(a.fps,a.x,a.y)
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    function animate(t){

        if(!stopAnimation){requestAnimationFrame(animate);}

        for(var i=0;i<animations.length;i++){
            var a=animations[i];
            if(!a.triggerTime){a.triggerTime=t+1000/a.fps;}
            if(t>a.triggerTime){
                a.triggerTime=t+1000/a.fps;
                a.frameCount++;
                ctx.clearRect(a.x+20,a.y-15,19,20)
                ctx.fillText(a.frameCount,a.x+20,a.y)
                ctx.fillRect(a.x+40,a.y-10,a.frameCount,15);
                if(a.x+40+a.frameCount>canvas.width-20){stopAnimation=true;}
            }
        }
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Using the timestamp feature of RAF to control fps</h4>
    <h4>Left#:fps, Mid#:Execution Count</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```